# Using fwrite in PHP but outputs odd error

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite, fclose

I am currently using fwrite, and this is what outputs as an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in /home/blah/blahblah.com/write/submit.php on line 5
```

The code goes like this:

```
$strlen  = strlen ( $_REQUEST["content"] );
$content = $_REQUEST["content"];
$title   = $_REQUEST["title"];
$fp      = fopen( "/home/blah/blahblah.com/write/texts/" . $_POST["title"] . ".txt" , a+ );
fwrite ( $fp , $content , $strlen );
fclose ( $fp );
```

Please help! I even tried to put in strlen of the text (which is unnecessary) so that it wouldn't expect anything else!

Comment: @vascowhite yeah, but I noticed most people came here with a bunch of code at hand and asking why this and that is like this and that, basically they are in a stage of debugging.

Comment: @vascowhite This is where everyone else debugs, why shouldn't I?

Answer (score 2):

The mode needs to be quoted:

```
$fp = fopen( "/home/blah/blahblah.com/write/texts/" . $_POST["title"] . ".txt" , "a+" );
```

It's currently being interpreted as an addition, I suspect.